# how to get value from the input tag when the user can add or remove them arbitrarily

Tags: javascript, html

here is my html and js code :

```js
function addInputColors(){
    var addInputElement = document.querySelector('.add-input-colors');
    var parent = document.querySelector('.colors-wrapper');
    addInputElement.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        var input = document.createElement('div');
        input.classList.add('colors-input');
        
        var deleteElement = document.createElement('div');
        deleteElement.classList.add('delete-color');
         deleteElement.innerHTML = "Delete";
       
        input.appendChild(deleteElement)
        var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
        inputElement.type = "text";
        inputElement.className ="input-colors";
        inputElement.placeholder ="Add color"
        input.insertBefore(inputElement,input.children[0]);
        parent.insertBefore(input ,parent.lastElementChild)
       
    var deleteElements = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-color');
    deleteElements.forEach(deleteElement =>{
        deleteElement.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
          
            e.target.parentElement.remove();
        })
    })


    })
}
addInputColors();
```

```css
.colors-input{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors-wrapper">
                                <div class="colors-input">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-colors" placeholder="add color">
                                     
                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="add-input-colors ">
                                   <span>Add</span>
                                    <div class="icon-add-wrapper_color">
                                        <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

As the title,how do I get the value of the input tags when someone else can optionally add or remove them.Are there any solutions to the above problem ? Thanks all !

Comment: Same way as non arbitrary ones. Maybe it helps you telling us, what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You may looking into MutationObserver

Comment: One way would be to maintain an array of references to the elements that are added or removed.

Comment: I am trying to get the value from the input tags

Comment: Your requirements are vague. One way you can get all the values from the inputs is: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.input-colors')).map(function(input) {return input.value;});`